# different result in response scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the price of a car, when I start scrapy.

```
scrapy shell https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear=2018&doFiltering=true&exSuppliers=&fromLocChoose=true&filterTo=49&dropLocationName=Buenos+Aires&emptySearchResults=false&ftsType=C&longitude=-58.3816&ftsLocationSearch=51&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay=25&chinese-license=on&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth=9&dropFtsInput=buenos+&dropCountry=Argentina&puDay=24&dropFtsLocationSearch=51&puHour=10&doMonthYear=9-2018&dropFtsEntry=18908&filterCoordinates=-34.44103514%2C-58.8644886&enabler=&puMonthYear=9-2018&distance=10&reducedCategory=small&ftsEntry=18908&city=Buenos+Aires&ordering=price&latitude=-34.6038&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter&dropCity=Buenos+Aires&dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete=Buenos+Aires%2C+Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete=Buenos+Aires%2C+Argentina&dropFtsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&dropCountryCode=&countryCode=&doMinute=0&advSearch=&filterAdditionalInfo=&puYear=2018&puSameAsDo=on&locationName=Buenos+Aires&puMinute=0&ftsInput=buenos+&coordinates=-34.6038%2C-58.3816&dropLocation=-1&doHour=10&dropCoordinates=-34.6038%2C-58.3816&ftsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&ftsSearch=L&location=-1&doMonth=9

fetch('https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear=2018&doFiltering=true&exSuppliers=&fromLocChoose=true&filterTo=49&dropLocationName=Buenos+Aires&emptySearchResults=false&ftsType=C&longitude=-58.3816&ftsLocationSearch=51&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay=25&chinese-license=on&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth=9&dropFtsInput=buenos+&dropCountry=Argentina&puDay=24&dropFtsLocationSearch=51&puHour=10&doMonthYear=9-2018&dropFtsEntry=18908&filterCoordinates=-34.44103514%2C-58.8644886&enabler=&puMonthYear=9-2018&distance=10&reducedCategory=small&ftsEntry=18908&city=Buenos+Aires&ordering=price&latitude=-34.6038&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter&dropCity=Buenos+Aires&dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete=Buenos+Aires%2C+Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete=Buenos+Aires%2C+Argentina&dropFtsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&dropCountryCode=&countryCode=&doMinute=0&advSearch=&filterAdditionalInfo=&puYear=2018&puSameAsDo=on&locationName=Buenos+Aires&puMinute=0&ftsInput=buenos+&coordinates=-34.6038%2C-58.3816&dropLocation=-1&doHour=10&dropCoordinates=-34.6038%2C-58.3816&ftsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&ftsSearch=L&location=-1&doMonth=9')
```

I try to get the value

```
response.css('span[class="carResultRow_Price-now"]::text').extract()
```

and the result is not the same as that shown on the website

```
['\n\t\t                                ARS1,584.37']
```

the correct value is 1,563.03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely this site handles requests differently based on the headers or another client details. Eg. price currency is based in your location. 
Take a look in the response you got using a browser with the command:

```
view(response)
```

The price should be the same as the one you got with Scrapy's parser.

You could try to make a request to look as close as browser request as possible (using the same `User-Agent` and `Accept`headers) in order to get the same price values.

Hope it helps.